# Easy way for Windows-based developer to view Android framework source code?

Tags: android, windows, open-source, frameworks

My immediate need is to take a peek at the source for EditTextPreference and see what I need to do to implement support for preferences with more structure. Can I run Git or repo under cygwin perhaps? Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Source Code is provided by the [Android Open Source Project](http://source.android.com/).
Inside the Page (Tab 'Source' -> Left Menu "Browse Source") you find a [link](https://android.googlesource.com) to browse the Source. The link will lead you to a git repository. There is a "search" field and I found 'EditTextPreference' using this field with the 'grep' option.

Answer (score 3):

If you just need to have a look at a single file you can use the web interface at https://android.googlesource.com.

If you want to check out the source tree you can use http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/

You probably want an ide to browse the code, so using the open source Eclipse or the free Intellij Community edition is recommended. In that case they both contain built-in git clients that you can use.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't have git built-in, but there is at least one plugin that you can use. I don't know about IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

Go to [Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch), and search with "android *your class*"

The first result for "EditTextPreference" is [what your looking for](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/preference/EditTextPreference.java&q=android%20EditTextPreference&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc).

You can browser the code source of Android's framework with this tool too. (and it works for Linux/Mac/Whatever users too ! ;)

Comment: Google Code Search is no longer working

Answer (score 0):

Using Windows I did this by using Ubuntu live CD, and downloading all the source code using the linux instructions here http://source.android.com/.

There are some commands you need to use for the code to be downloaded to your main hardrive. I wrote a blog post about it here: http://udinic.wordpress.com/2011/11/18/the-source-for-all-goodness/